# Watermelon Wheat Beer - Bitter Taste

Tags: secondary-fermentation, fruit

After a week of primary fermentation, I tried adding about 8 pounds of watermelon puree to my secondary fermenter and took a gravity and taste test 10 days later.  The beer still tastes very tart/bitter and not like fresh watermelon.  Any advice? Should I be using a combination of fresh watermelon and watermelon extract?  Will the flavor improve after carbonation? Should I have used more or less watermelon puree?  Should I have used watermelon juice instead of puree?

Also, since I hope to brew a few more fruit beers, I noticed the colour of wheat extract beer is very dark.  Should I be using a combination of liquid wheat extract and golden extract to get a more yellow colour?

I have already read this post:

[Watermelon beer, anyone tried brewing?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/watermelon-beer-anyone-tried-brewing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed over time that you want use lots and lots of fruit (if you think you used enough, add more), supplement with extract, puree the flesh (no rinds or skins) or use juice if possible, boiling kills some flavors, and don't use clarifying agents.

You can probably substitute some of your wheat extract with light LME or DME. Depends on your recipe. Ask your LHBS.

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult to impossible to get much flavor out of watermelon due to its water content.  There just isn't a of of flavor there to start with, and any sugars in the watermelon will be consumed by the yeast.